# Apple developer account :- how to change the "agent name"?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I need to change agent name,is there any way to do it?

[image]

Comment: contact to Apple and ask them to update it; they may do it for you, they may not.

Answer (score 1):

I just filled [Apple Developer Program Support form](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/) and explained my situation. After a couple of hours, got an email saying they fixed it.

BTW, it was misspelled and they fixed it, I didn't ask to change the whole name.[image]

Comment: Well,In  ma case i want to change the whole name.

Answer (score 0):

I received mail from apple team,

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/MemberCenter_Recipes/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers.html

https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/